# US Immigration I-485 Application

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

During I-485 process the case has shown "Response To USCIS' Request For Evidence Was Received" since July'2016.

Is this normal, I would have expected them to accept or reject the information I've sent?

When (or will) the status change to whatever is the next step?

Comment: You'll probably find out whether they've accepted or rejected it when they approve or deny the application.

Comment: Regarding your edit: I expect the next step will be approval or denial of your application.  I have no idea when this will be.  Disclaimer: I haven't gone through this process myself, so I am guessing based on my own experiences with other bureaucratic processes along with anecdotal evidence from others' experiences with various immigration systems.